# Simplify how to find unique rows of a Matlab array

Tags: matlab

I would like your help to vectorise (or, more generally, make more efficient) a Matlab code where:

- **Step 1:** I construct a matrix `C` of size `sgxR`, where each row contains a sequence of ones and zeros, according to whether certain logical conditions are satisfied.
- **Step 2:** I identify the  indices of the unique rows of `C`.

I now describe the code in more details.

**Step 1:** Creation of the matrix `C`. I divide this step in 3 sub-steps.

**Step 1.a:**  Create the `1x3` cell `U_grid`. For `j=1,2,3`, `U_grid{j}` is a `sg x K` matrix of numbers.

```
clear
rng default

n_U_sets=3; %This parameter will not be changed
sg=4; %sg is usually quite large, for instance 10^6
K=5; %This parameter can range between 3 and 8
Ugrid=cell(n_U_sets,1);
for j=1:n_U_sets
Ugrid{j}=randn(sg,K);
end
```

**Step 1.b:** For each `g=1,...,sg`

- Take the 3  rows  `Ugrid{1}(g,:), Ugrid{2}(g,:),  Ugrid{3}(g,:)`.
- Take all possible `1x3` rows that can be formed such that the first element is  from `Ugrid{1}(g,:)`, the second element is   from
  `Ugrid{2}(g,:)`, and the third element is from `Ugrid{3}(g,:)`. There are `K^3` such rows.
- Create the matrix `D{g}` storing row-wise all possible **pairs** of such `1x3` rows. `D{g}` will have size `(K^3*(K^3-1)/2)x6`

This is coded as:

```
%Row indices of all possible pairs of rows  
[y, x] = find(tril(logical(ones(K^(n_U_sets))), -1));
indices_pairs = [x, y]; %K^3*(K^3-1)/2

%Create D{g}
for g=1:sg  
    vectors = cellfun(@(x) {x(g,:)}, Ugrid); %1x3
     T_temp = cell(1,n_U_sets);
     [T_temp{:}] = ndgrid(vectors{:});
     T_temp = cat(n_U_sets+1, T_temp{:});
     T = reshape(T_temp,[],n_U_sets);
     D{g}=[T(indices_pairs(:,1),:) T(indices_pairs(:,2),:)];  %(K^3*(K^3-1)/2) x (6)
end
```

**Step 1.c:** From `D` create `C`. Let `R=(K^3*(K^3-1)/2)`. `R` is the size of any `D{g}`. `C` is a `sg x R` matrix constructed as follows: for `g=1,...,sg` and for `r=1,...,R`

- if `D{g}(r,1)>=D{g}(r,5)+D{g}(r,6)` or  `D{g}(r,4)<=D{g}(r,2)+D{g}(r,3)`
- then `C(g,r)=1`
- otherwise `C(g,r)=0`

This is coded as:

```
R=(K^(n_U_sets)*(K^(n_U_sets)-1)/2);
C=zeros(sg,R);
for g=1:sg
for r=1:R
    if D{g}(r,1)>=D{g}(r,5)+D{g}(r,6) || D{g}(r,4)<=D{g}(r,2)+D{g}(r,3) 
       C(g,r)=1;
    end
end
end
```

**Step 2:** Assign the same index to any two rows of `C` that are equal.

```
[~,~,idx] = unique(C,"rows");
```

**Question: Steps 1.b and 1.c are the critical ones.** With `sg` large and `K` between 3 and 8, they take a lot of time, due to the loop and `reshape`.  Do you see any way to simplify them, for instance by vectorising?

Comment: This is extremely difficult to follow. I'm not sure that "please help me improve my code" is on-topic for this site, but it might help if you described what your inputs and outputs represent so it's clearer what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've tried to simplify it and break it in pieces. Please let me know if it looks better now.

Comment: Step 2 looks like the answer is `[~,~,idx] = unique(criterion_2,"rows");` but "assign the same index" is a confusing description that doesn't precisely mean anything in MATLAB terms. It doesn't seem there's really any helpful connection between the steps - you would probably be better off breaking into two questions, then you could provide simple examples of input and output without worrying whether the example in each case is too simple to work with the other part.

Comment: Thanks. I have removed other useless parts. I'm not sure how to simplify more while maintaining the key core f my question.

Comment: Just to be clear, is Step 2 essentially solved from that comment? It doesn't seem to contribute anything to the question now, it's just a question about building `C` - which is fine but would be a step towards a simpler question to remove the bits about unique row indices.

Comment: The comment has solved step 2. However, I'd prefer to keep it, just to show that `idx` is ultimately what I want. I'm not interested in `C` "per se". Maybe this can be useful in an attempt to vectorise.